# Characteristic function on I is uncountable

Tags: real-analysis, integers, characteristic-functions, characteristics

I studied characteristic function in real analysis in Richard R goldberg book for methods of real analysis and there is an exercise problem asking to prive that characteristic function on I is uncountable.

My attempt:if we composite every function whose range is I with the characteristic function on I we would still get a characteristic function on I.
ie., if f is a function whose range is I and χ is the characteristic function on I then

χ○f is a characteristic function on I

But my doubt is, Is the set of all functions whose range is I is uncountable?

I saw some proof using the help of power set of I. I didn't understand it. Please help me with the proof.

Comment: Could you write it more mathematically with some mathjax? This would save us some trouble analyzing what you try to express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to consider two cases:

1. $I$ is finite.
2. $I$ is not finite.

Since the set of characteristic functions on $I$ is in bijection with its power set $\mathcal{P}(I)$ we can answer this very quickly since $\mathcal{P}(I)$ is countable off $I$ is finite… thus either it is finite or uncountable!

Beware: by countable I mean $\sharp I \leq 
\aleph_0$ si finite sets are also countable with my definition!

Comment: Can you explain how the characteristic functions on I is in bijection with P(I) please

Comment: You associate to a subset $J$ the function $\chi_J$ I let you find the inverse :)

Comment: This is an easy exercise, I don’t “let you down” I think if you manage it yourself you will understand the topic better